# Xaml inside ContentControl and binding to DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have two questions about developing at Windows Phone:

I want to create custom control and be able to provide some extra XAML inside it. So I use `ContentControl` with `ContentPresenter` inside `ControlTemplate`.

```
<ContentControl>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockControl" Text="Existing controls"/>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

It worked, but I can't access `TextBlockControl` inside `ControlTemplate` from code-behind. `FindName` always returns null.

Secondly, I want to provide attributes for Control, so I create DependencyProperty like this:

```
public string CustomText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CustomTextProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(CustomTextProperty, value);
        TextBlockControl.Text = value;
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CustomText", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), null);
```

As you can see, I write `TextBlockControl.Text = value;` to set text for TextBlock inside of my Control. When I set static string - it works

```
<MyControl CustomText="Static Text"/>
```

But when I want to use `Binding` (e.g. for `LocalizedStrings` resource) - it doesn't work. Am i missing PropertyMeta Callback, or some IPropertyChanged inheritance? I have read tons of StackOverflow questions with the same issue, but nothing answered my questions.

Answer (score 2):

the answer to the first question :

If you créate your custom-control, and you assign a template, you can Access to the elements in that template using :

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "TextBlockControl", Type = typeof(FrameworkElement))]
```

You have to put this attribute in order to tools like blend, know that the template for this custom-control has to have a textblock called TextBlockControl.Then from the control's OnApplyTemplate you should get a reference to it whit :

```
 protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _part1 = this.GetTemplateChild("TextBlockControl") as FrameworkElement;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it later. BTW, do you know, if ControlTemplate is the only possible way to insert user XAML into control's XAML?

Comment: Hi Wayne, in .NET there are two ways of creating a contro. A user control or a custom-control. The user control is when you want to mix several controls into one control, to reuse it along your App. The custom control, normally inherits from an existing control, like a GridView, StackPanel, Button... in order to enhance it's behaviors. Maybe the best way for you is to start with the user controls. Hope it helps!

Comment: Usercontrol is not suit for my purposes. I want to add extra XAML outside, not just group controls

Comment: Your code worked, thanks! But now I don't have access to elements that I pass to control, they are visible in code-behind, but they all are null.

Comment: I can get access to them only using Loaded event in XAML and then converting sender to its type. It's awfull way.

Comment: I believe that's the only way to do it.