# How to Get element inside the content control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to find the element inside the content control :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourChoices}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="ccBloodGroup">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbBloodGroup" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="331" Height="45">
                                <ComboBoxItem>A+</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>A-</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>B+</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>B-</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>O+</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>O-</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>AB+</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>AB-</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text=" Blood Type" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger SourceName="cbBloodGroup" Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
```

I found an answer on Internet as

```
 ComboBox cb = ccBloodGroup.ContentTemplate.FindName("cbBloodGroup", ccBloodGroup) as ComboBox;
```

But this is giving me an run time exception saying 'This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied.'

Please help..

Comment: You can only use that after `OnApplyTemplate` of the control itself is called. If you want to be able to refer `ccBloodGroup` in your code behind, you can add a loaded event for it in xaml, however it would be better to tell us exactly why you want that and what your actual goal is, because this is not the `MVVM` way.

Comment: Similiar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679648/why-would-this-contenttemplate-findname-throw-an-invalidoperationexception-on) - call this.ApplyTemplate(); before calling FindName

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xaml inside ContentControl and binding to DependencyProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809073/xaml-inside-contentcontrol-and-binding-to-dependencyproperty)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method will help you:

```
public T FindElementByName<T>(FrameworkElement element, string sChildName) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
            T childElement = null;
            var nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
            for (int i = 0; i < nChildCount; i++)
            {
                FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;

                if (child == null)
                    continue;

                if (child is T && child.Name.Equals(sChildName))
                {
                    childElement = (T)child;
                    break;
                }

                childElement = FindElementByName<T>(child, sChildName);

                if (childElement != null)
                    break;
            } 
            return childElement;
    }
```

And, how I use it, just add button, and on button Click:

```
 private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = FindElementByName<ComboBox>(ccBloodGroup, "cbBloodGroup");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to provide an element that (as the error says) has the `Template` applied. Your `ccBloodGroup` control is inside the `DataTemplate` and so clearly, does not have this `Template` applied to it.

For example, an element that might have this `Template` applied to it would be the `ContentPresenter`s of the items in the `YourChoices` collection that are using this `DataTemplate` to define what they look like in the UI.

You can find out full details as usual on MSDN, with a detailed example on the [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page, but it goes something like this... from the example on the linked page:

```
// Getting the currently selected ListBoxItem 
// Note that the ListBox must have 
// IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to True for this to work
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.
    ContainerFromItem(myListBox.Items.CurrentItem));

// Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

// Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", 
    myContentPresenter);

// Do something to the DataTemplate-generated TextBlock
MessageBox.Show("The text of the TextBlock of the selected list item: "
+ myTextBlock.Text);
```

> The `FindVisualChild` method is shown on the linked page.

Comment: Sorry but I dint get how those two separate controls are communicating. :( I have comboBox inside the DataTemplate & need to access it. Also If I do something like this, ComboBox myListBoxItem = (ComboBox)(cbBloodGroup.ItemContainerGenerator.
                ContainerFromItem(cbBloodGroup.Items.CurrentItem)); It does not recognize cbBloodGroup.

Comment: Please read my answer and the linked MSDN page again. You get the `ContentPresenter` *of the item that has the `DataTemplate` applied*, not any element inside the `DataTemplate`.